# How to create a table of contents on the left side of the document in libreoffice?

Tags: libreoffice-writer

How to create and table of content like this on the side rather than in the page itself :
[image]

Also, can i port it to Microsoft office if index and table of content created like this in libreoffice

Answer (score 0):

Just insert a Frame, resize and move it to its final location, put the Cursor into the Frame, and create the ToC there (you may have to adjust the tabstops if the frame takes only half of the page's width). Generally, contents should be available in MS Word, too, but you may have to adjust styles (tabstops, indentation and so on; ToC functionality may be lost). But i don't recommend to switch between MSO and LO; since LO is freely available for Windows, i recommend to keep working with LO.